# Add button is used to display dropdown and when select dropdown get displayed without null value then other dropdown should appear

Tags: php, jquery, css

```
<p class="hide_editor_sub subject-hide">
                            <label for="subject_tertiary">Dertiary Subject Area:</label>
                            <select name="subject_tertiary" id="subject_tertiary" class="subject-select"
                                    onchange="LoadCoAuthors();">
                                <option value="-1">None</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($subject_areas as $subject_area) {
                                    $selected = $unit->getSubjectArea(10) == $subject_area->getSubjectAreaId() ? "selected" : "";
                                    echo "<option value='" . $subject_area->getSubjectAreaId() . "' $selected>" . $subject_area->getName() . "</option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select><button id="remove_button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-project" style=" margin-left: 10px">Remove</button>
                        </p>

                        <button id='show_add_button_sub' type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="display: block;">Add Evaluator</button>
```

Add button is used to display dropdown and when select dropdown get displayed without null value then other dropdown should appear

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and what the problem is you're having.

Comment: Hi sorry some of the contents didn't uploaded propely. But i will try to explain. so, as site appears, 2-3 dropdown gets uploaded whose value is not equals to null. Now, any dropdown appears then the other dropdown respectively also should show up

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little unclear, but this is a link to what I believe to be a similar question. From what I can tell, you want to display a second drop down only on certain conditions. You'll want to use the .change function that detects when something has changed (in this case the first drop down). You can then check if the value is not null and use the .show or .hide for the second drop down. [Show content of 2nd Drop down after 1st Drop down getting selected.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195223/show-content-of-2nd-drop-down-after-1st-drop-down-getting-selected)

Comment: Hi sorry some of the contents didnt uploaded propely.

Comment: Hi sorry some of the contents didn't uploaded propely. But i will try to explain. so, as site appears, 2-3 dropdown gets uploaded whose value is not equals to null. Now, any dropdown appears then the other dropdown respectively also should show up

Comment: Have you tried to implement something similar to the link I suggested above? I think with some modifications, it would work for what you are trying to accomplish.